# SIGINFO's si_pid sets itself to 0 after a few calls of the same function

Tags: c, signals, sigaction

I'm working on a simple project that makes 2 processes communicate to each other using signals. More specifically, I'm using **sigaction** with the flag **SA_SIGINFO** so that each process can identify who sent it a signal and reply.
Thing is, after they call each other a few times (it can vary a lot, sometimes it happens after 3 exchanges, other times, after 700), **siginfo returns a si_pid that is equal to 0**.
Here are both codes I'm using to make them communicate.
First, the *"server"*

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void    ft_respond(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    static int  i = 0;
    (void)context;
    if (sig == SIGUSR1)
    {
        i++;
        printf("received - %d PID: %d\n", i, info->si_pid);
        if (info ->si_pid != 0)
            kill(info->si_pid, SIGUSR1);
        if (i == 5000)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction    reaction;
    sigset_t            mask;

    reaction.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    reaction.sa_sigaction = ft_respond;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &reaction, NULL);
    printf("PID = %d\n", getpid());
    while (1)
        pause();
    return(0);
}
```

And second, the *"client"*

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void    ft_send_signal(int pid)
{
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
    printf("sent\n");
}

void    ft_signal_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    static int  i = 0;

    (void)context;
    if (sig == SIGUSR1)
    {
        printf("recieved - %d PID: %d\n", i, info->si_pid);
        i++;
        if (info->si_pid != 0)
            kill(info->si_pid, SIGUSR1);
        if (i == 5000)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    struct sigaction    action;
    sigset_t            set;
    
    if (ac != 2)
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    action.sa_sigaction = ft_signal_handler;
    action.sa_mask = set;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);
    ft_send_signal(atoi(av[1]));
    while(1)
        pause();
    return (0);
}
```

Notes:

- If I remove the line `if (info ->si_pid != 0)`, the process not receiving a signal pauses forever (duh!) and interestingly enough, the other one keeps on going like it is receiving signals forever (not duh!).
- I have looked around to understand how I could use sigfillset or sigaddset in order to prevent any incoming signal while my handler is still working, nothing seems to disrupt this behaviour.
- I am running this program on a MacBook, if you're wondering.
- I have also run the programs on Linux (Ubuntu-based distro) and I get no "bug" there. Which seems odd to me.
- If you want to test the code, it is sort of straightforward: compile each program with a distinct name (e.g. **`gcc -o server server.c && gcc -o client client.c`**), run the server first, then run the client with the server's PID as a parameter.
- Before I get flamed for using **printf** with signals, I know it is not recommended in case of signal interruption during printf execution (see [How to avoid using `printf()` in a signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16891019/)), but theoretically, handler is done when sending out its signal so it should work well. I have tried using **write** function instead, it has the same behaviour.

If you have ANY lead I can follow for this to work without a hic, I'll be really grateful.

Comment: *Before I get flamed for using **printf** with signals ...*  Seriously?  "I'm having intermittent problems with signals not working as expected, but trust me, the undefined behavior I'm invoking by calling both `printf()` and `exit()` from within my signal handlers isn't the problem"?!?!?!  *I have tried using **write** function instead, it has the same behaviour.*  Then why on God's good Earth are you using `printf()`?  You've already implemented it properly with `write()`.  You have something you can't solve, and you leave in undefined behavior?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after playing around, I stumbled on a clean solution. Since the programs are randomly losing track of the `info->si_pid`, I stored its value into a `static int id` and removed the condition `if (info->si_pid != 0)`. Since now, if info->si_pid == 0, my id still has the pid in store.
Here's how it looks. I pushed the exchanges to 50000 and it works like a charm, each time.

Server:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void    ft_respond(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    static int  i = 0;
    static int  id = 0;

    if (info->si_pid != 0)
        id = info->si_pid;
    (void)context;
    if (sig == SIGUSR1)
    {
        i++;
        printf("received - %d PID: %d\n", i, id);
        kill(id, SIGUSR1);
        if (i == 50000)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    return ;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction    reaction;

    reaction.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&reaction.sa_mask);
    reaction.sa_sigaction = ft_respond;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &reaction, NULL);
    printf("PID = %d\n", getpid());
    while (1)
        pause();
    return(0);
}
```

Client:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void    ft_send_signal(int pid)
{
    kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
    printf("sent\n");
}

void    ft_signal_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    static int  i = 0;
    static int  id = 0;

    if (info->si_pid != 0)
        id = info->si_pid;
    (void)context;
    if (sig == SIGUSR1)
    {
        printf("recieved - %d PID: %d\n", i, id);
        i++;
        kill(id, SIGUSR1);
        if (i == 50000)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    return ;
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    struct sigaction    action;
    
    if (ac != 2)
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    action.sa_sigaction = ft_signal_handler;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);
    ft_send_signal(atoi(av[1]));
    usleep(100);
    while(1)
        pause();
    return (0);
}
```

Now it appears that no matter what, the processes keep on sending signals to each other.

Answer (score 1):

#### Diagnosis

Most of the time, when I was testing on a MacBook Pro running Big Sur 11.6.3, the commands run to completion.  I'm using a program `tester` to run the server and then the client — the advantage of the program is that I can report the exit statuses of the client and server programs accurately.  I've been using increasingly elaborate test rigs to capture the information.

Every so often, I seem to get the server dying immediately.  I believe that's a **timing issue** due to the o/s scheduler.  The launch code runs the client after launching the server, but it so happens that the system scheduler runs the client before the server has set up its signal handler and so the server is killed by the client's initial signal.

#### Supporting Evidence

I modified both the client and server programs to include `alarm(15);` so that the processes time out after 15 seconds.  Most of the time, it takes the pair less than a second to complete.  On those occasions when things fail, I get the server exiting with status 0x001E (which indicates it died from a SIGUSR1 signal) and on the same runs, the client exits 15 seconds later with status 0x000E (which indicates it died from a SIGALRM signal).  The log files contain no '`received`" messages.

```
$ rmk && timecmd -m -- ./tester | tpipe -sx "grep -c -e '^C received'" "grep -c -e '^S received'" "grep -E -e 'PID =|^Child|(Server|Client) PID'"  "cat > log.$(isodate -c)"
2022-02-15 14:25:07.172 [PID 10210] ./tester
tpipe: + grep -c -e '^C received'
tpipe: + grep -c -e '^S received'
tpipe: + grep -E -e 'PID =|^Child|(Server|Client) PID'
tpipe: + cat > log.20220215.142507
Server PID: 10211
Client PID: 10212
10212: sent signal to PID = 10211
Child 10211 exited with status 0x001E
Child 10212 exited with status 0x000E
2022-02-15 14:25:22.193 [PID 10210; status 0x0000]  -  15.021s
0
0
$
```

The status message for 10211 appeared almost immediately; that for 10212 waited for just over 15 seconds.  The two zeros are from the `grep -c` commands — there were no interesting messages.

For contrast, the prior run showed:

```
$ rmk && timecmd -m -- ./tester | tpipe -sx "grep -c -e '^C received'" "grep -c -e '^S received'" "grep -E -e 'PID =|^Child|(Server|Client) PID'"  "cat > log.$(isodate -c)"
2022-02-15 14:25:05.965 [PID 10196] ./tester
tpipe: + grep -c -e '^C received'
tpipe: + grep -c -e '^S received'
tpipe: + grep -E -e 'PID =|^Child|(Server|Client) PID'
tpipe: + cat > log.20220215.142505
Server PID: 10197
Client PID: 10198
PID = 10197
10198: sent signal to PID = 10197
Child 10197 exited with status 0x0000
Child 10198 exited with status 0x0000
2022-02-15 14:25:06.481 [PID 10196; status 0x0000]  -  0.515s
5000
5000
$
```

The 5000 entries here are the counts from the `grep -c` commands run via the `tpipe` program.  (The `rmk` is a variant of `make`; `tpipe` is a program a bit like `tee` except it writes to processes rather than files (see also the unfortunately named [`pee`](https://www.putorius.net/linux-pee-command-tee-standard-input-into-pipes.html) program); `isodate` prints the date in a compressed ISO 8601 format such as `20220215.142505`; `timecmd -m` executes a command and times it to milliseconds, reporting the command and the status, etc.)

I've not logged a case where `info->si_pid == 0`, nor a case where there's a problem after some intermediate number of signal exchanges — it's been 0 or 5000 and no other value.  Consequently, I may not have accurately reproduced your scenario.

Using a shell script to launch the server and then the client didn't reproduce the premature signal — the delays inherent in processing a shell script seem to be just enough to allow the server to set up its signal processing before the client sends the initial signal.

Script tested:

```
time=$(isodate -c)
server > server.$time.log &
client $! > client.$time.log
```

#### Modified Code

JFTR, here's my revised code.  It uses some code that is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

#### `client.c`

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stderr.h"

static void ft_send_signal(int pid)
{
    if (kill(pid, SIGUSR1) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to send initial signal to PID %d: ", pid);
    printf("%d: sent signal to PID = %d\n", getpid(), pid);
    fflush(stdout);
}

static void ft_signal_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    static int  i = 0;

    (void)context;
    if (sig == SIGUSR1)
    {
        printf("C received - %d PID: %d\n", i, info->si_pid);
        fflush(stdout);
        i++;
        if (info->si_pid != 0)
        {
            if (kill(info->si_pid, SIGUSR1) != 0)
                err_syserr("failed to send signal to PID %d: ", info->si_pid);
        }
        else
            err_error("info->si_pid == 0 at iteration %d\n", i);
        if (i == 5000)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    err_setarg0("client");
    struct sigaction    action;
    sigset_t            set;

    if (ac != 2)
        err_usage("PID");

    alarm(15);
    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    action.sa_sigaction = ft_signal_handler;
    action.sa_mask = set;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);
    ft_send_signal(atoi(av[1]));
    while(1)
        pause();
    return (0);
}
```

#### `server.c`

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stderr.h"

static void ft_respond(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    static int  i = 0;
    (void)context;
    if (sig == SIGUSR1)
    {
        i++;
        printf("S received - %d PID: %d\n", i, info->si_pid);
        fflush(stdout);
        if (info->si_pid != 0)
        {
            if (kill(info->si_pid, SIGUSR1) != 0)
                err_syserr("failed to send signal to PID %d: ", info->si_pid);
        }
        else
            err_error("info->si_pid == 0 at iteration %d\n", i);
        if (i == 5000)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    err_setarg0("server");
    struct sigaction    reaction;

    sigemptyset(&reaction.sa_mask);
    alarm(15);
    reaction.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    reaction.sa_sigaction = ft_respond;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &reaction, NULL);
    printf("PID = %d\n", getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
    while (1)
        pause();
    return(0);
}
```

#### `tester.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stderr.h"

int main(void)
{
    err_setarg0("tester");
    alarm(20);
    pid_t server = fork();
    if (server < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to fork for server: ");
    if (server == 0)
    {
        char *args[] = { "./server", 0 };
        execv(args[0], args);
        err_syserr("failed to exec server: ");
    }
    printf("Server PID: %d\n", server);
    fflush(stdout);

    pid_t client = fork();
    if (client < 0)
        err_syserr("failed to fork for client: ");
    if (client == 0)
    {
        char buffer[20];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d", server);
        char *argc[] = { "./client", buffer, 0 };
        execv(argc[0], argc);
        err_syserr("failed to exec client: ");
    }
    printf("Client PID: %d\n", client);
    fflush(stdout);

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        printf("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Prescription

I'm not sure that there's a good way to fix this other than adding a call to the client code to delay it from sending the initial signal for some significant time — a millisecond or two would probably be sufficient.  This delay would mean that the server has time to set up its signal handling.  Equivalently, the `tester` program could add a delay between launching the server and the client.

Why no problem on Linux?  Luck?  Or the o/s scheduler doesn't run the second child of `tester` before the first child, so the server always gets to set up its signal handling before the client sends the first signal.

Comment: First, thanks a lot for the time you invested in replying to my question.
After reading you, I tried delaying both calls from the server and the client by using *usleep(10)* and it just worked wonders. So it looks like you were right in your assumptions. Again, thanks a LOT! You helped a great deal