UNIX Signal mistreated for communication suddenly receives from pid 0
I am doing a test setup where I use UNIX signals for communication.
The following code uses SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 to transfer a string from a client process to a server process that will listen for incoming signals. I know this is not how signals should be used and I kindly ask you to disregard any "that function is not signal-safe", because in this test setup the client will wait for the server to acknowledge each received bit via a signal back to the client which will in turn as answer to that signal send the next bit to the server.
This way no signal should interrupt while a signal is being handled. Or so I think at least... I am not sure on anything right now anymore...
The problem is that I suddenly receive signals from pid 0 (which is broadcast?) but I never send a broadcast. The code will work for smaller strings but getting larger (~100 chars) it will sometimes work and sometimes not. I could deal with this situation by just sending->sleep->sending in the client, which would be slower but I am really interested in what is going on here.
Here is the server code:
void    sig_handler(int _signum, siginfo_t *_info, void *_context)
{
    static unsigned char    str[MAX_MSG_SIZE];
    static int              str_i;
    t_bool                  done;
    int                     i;

    if (_info->si_pid != 0)
    {
        
        if (((str_i++) * 0) || _signum == SIGUSR2)
            str[(str_i - 1) / 8] |= 1 << (7 - (((str_i - 1) % 8)));
        done = !(str_i % 8) && !str[(str_i / 8) - 1];
        if (done)
        {
            i = ((str_i / 8 - 4) >= 0) * (str_i / 8 - 4)
                + ((str_i / 8 - 4) < 0) * -1;//this saves a line...

            while (++i < str_i / 8)
                if (str[i] == 0xf0)
                    done = FALSE;
        }
        if ((str_i / 8 == MAX_MSG_SIZE || done) && _info->si_pid != 0)
        {
            ft_printf("kill\n");
            write(1, str, str_i / 8);
            ft_memset(str, 0, MAX_MSG_SIZE);
            str_i = 0;
            kill(_info->si_pid, SIGUSR2);
        }
        else if (_info->si_pid != 0)
            kill(_info->si_pid, SIGUSR1);
        else ft_printf("wtf");

    }
    else ft_printf("\nOH WTF IS HAPPENING\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction    sa;

    ft_printf("%d\n", getpid());
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGUSR2);
    sa.sa_sigaction = sig_handler;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO;
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL) == -1
        || sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sa, NULL) == -1)
        return (0);
    while (TRUE)
        sleep(10000);
    return (0);
}

Notice i added allot of print statements to find out what is happening.
here is the client:
typedef struct s_client_info
{
    int     pid;
    char    *str;
    int     i;
    t_bool  run;
}   t_client_info;

void    sig_handler(int _signum, siginfo_t *_info, void *_context)
{
    static t_client_info    *v;

    //usleep(200);
    if (_info  && !_info->si_pid) //this prints 0-n times randomly at any moment
        ft_printf("wtf");
    if (!_signum && !_info) //setup
    {
        v = _context;
        v->run = TRUE;
    }
    if (_signum == SIGUSR2 || !v->run) //received stop signal from server
    {
        v->run = FALSE;
        return ;
    }

    if (v->pid == 0) //is never called
        ft_printf("Wtf1");

    if ((v->str[v->i / 8] << (v->i % 8)) & 0b10000000) //extracts current bit
        kill(v->pid, SIGUSR2); //send '1' to server
    else
        kill(v->pid, SIGUSR1); //send '0' to server
    v->i++;
}

int main(int _argc, char *_argv[])
{
    t_client_info       v;
    struct sigaction    sa;
    int                 i;

//check input
    i = -1;
    while (_argv[1][++i])
        if (_argv[1][i] < '0' || _argv[1][i] > '9')
            return (print_usage(), 0);
    if (_argc != 3)
        return (print_usage(), 0);
//prepare client info
    v.pid = ft_atoi(_argv[1]);
    v.str = _argv[2];
    v.i = 0;

//register signal handler
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGUSR2);
    sa.sa_sigaction = sig_handler;
    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL) == -1
        || sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sa, NULL) == -1)
        return (0);
//start sending
    sig_handler(0, NULL, &v);
    while (v.run)
        usleep(10);
    return (0);
}

If I uncomment that usleep, the communication will work, but the client will still sometimes receive a signal from pid 0 and print "wtf"
I thought maybe another process is sending a broadcast randomly, so i set up an extra process that checks for that... nope there is no other process. somehow one of these or both end up sending a malformed signal.
This is some output from the server. After receiving the same message for a 3. time it will fail and never send the stop signal(SIGUSR2) to the client
wiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhkill
wiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuh

OH WTF IS HAPPENING
I needed to stop the client manually at this point.
So I added this in the client and enabled the usleep again to check whether the weird pid = 0 signals come in at some specific time:
if ((v->str[v->i / 8] << (v->i % 8)) & 0b10000000)
        ft_printf("1"),kill(v->pid, SIGUSR2);
    else
        ft_printf("0"),kill(v->pid, SIGUSR1);

And they just drop in randomly. here is an example:
./client 19863
wiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuhwiegyhweoufgiaqefouhqaefouhqofsuh
111100001001111110011000100000000111011101101001011001010110011101111001011010000111011101100101011011110111010101100110011001110110100101100001011100010110010101100110011011110111010101101000011100010110000101100101011001100110111101110101011010000111000101101111011001100111001101110101011010001111000010011111100110001000000001110111011010010110010101100111011110010110100001110111011001010110111101110101011001100110011101101001011000010111000101100101011001100110111101110101011010000111000101100001011001010110011001101111011101010110100001110001011011110110011001110011011101010110100011110000100111111001100010000000011101110110100101100101011001110111100101101000011101110110010101101111011101010110011001100111011010010110000101110001011001010110011001101111011101010110100001110001011000010110010101100110011011110111010101101000011100010110111101100110011100110111010101101000111100001001111110011000100000000111011101101001011001010110011101111001011010000111011101100101011011110111010101100110011001110110100101100001011100010110010101100110011011110111010101101000011100010110000101100101011001100110111101110101011010000111000101101111011001100111001101110101011010001111000010011111100110001000000001110111011010010110010101100111011110010110100001110111011001010110111101110101011001100110011101101001011000010111000101100101011001100110111101110101011010000111000101100001011001010110011001101111011101010110100001110
wtf
00101101111011001100111001101110101011010001111000010011111100110001000000001110111011010010110010101100111011110010110100001110111011001010110111101110101011001100110011101101001011000010111000101100101011001100110111101110101011010000111000101100001011001010110011001101111011101010110100001110001011011110110011001110011011101010110100011110000100111111001100010000000011101110110100101100101011001110111100101101000011101110110010101101111011101010110011001100111011010010110000101110001011001010110011001101111011101010110100001110001011000010110010101100110011011110111010101101000011100010110111101100110011100110111010101101000111100001001111110011000100000000111011101101001011001010110011101111001011010000111011101100101011011110111010101100110011001110110100101100001011100010110010101100110011011110111010101101000011100010110000101100101011001100110111101110101011010000111000101101111011001100111001101110101011010001111000010011111100110001000000001110111011010010110010101100111011110010110100001110111011001010110111101110101011001100110011101101001011000010111000101100101011001100110111101110101011010000111000101100001011001010110011001101111011101010110100001110001011011110110011001110011011101010110100011110000100111111001100010000000011101110110100101100101011001110111100101101000011101110110010101101111011101010110011001100111011010010110000101110001011001010110011001101111011101010110100001110001011000010110010101100110011011110111010101101000011100010110111101100110011100110111010101101000111100001001111110011000100000000111011101101001011001010110011101111001011010000111011101100101011011110111010101100110011001110110100101100001011100010110010101100110011011110111010101101000011100010110000101100101011001100110111101110101011010000111000101101111011001100111001101110101011010001111000010011111100110001000000001110111011010010110010101100111011110010110100001110111011001010110111101110101011001100110011101101001011000010111000101100101011001100110111101110101011010000111000101100001011001010110011001101111011101010110100001110001011011110110011001110011011101010110100011110000100111111001100010000000011101110110100101100101011001110111100101101000011101110110010101101111011101010110011001100111011010010110000101110001011001010110011001101111011101010110100001110001011000010110010101100110011011110111010101101000011100010110111101100110011100110111010101101000111100001001111110011000100000000111011101101001011001010110011101111001011010000111011101100101011011110111010101100110011001110110100101100001011100010110010101100110011011110111010101101000011100010110000101100101011001100110111101110101011010000111000101101111011001100111001101110101011010001111000010011111100110001000000001110111011010010110010101100111011110010110100001110111011001010110
wtf
1111011101010110011001100111011010010110000101110001011001010110011001101111011101010110100001110001011000010110010101100110011011110111010101101000011100010110111101100110011100110111010101101000111100001001111110011000100000000111011101101001011001010110011101111001011010000111011101100101011011110111010101100110011001
wtf
1101101001011000010111000101100101011001100110111101110101011010000111000101100001011001010110011001101111011101010110100001110001011011110110011001110011011101010110100011110000100111111001100010000000011101110110100101100101011001110111100101101000011101110110010101101111011101010110011001100111011010010110000101110001011001010110011001101111011101010110100001110001011000010110010101100110011011110111010101101000011100010110111101100
wtf
11001110011011101010110100000000000

here is another screenshot of a run without the usleep in client:
Server left, Client right.
After that I send a small message to the server without restarting it and it suddenly send an extremly large message out of nowhere. Pages of 0s and 1s with just ./client pid asd.
This was the servers reaction:
The topmost message was the last from the last image
Does anyone have an idea what is happening?
I thought by always reacting to a signal i should not go into any race condition but this behavior is just over my head.
UPDATE:
I used tried using the solution in the related question dimich commented (SIGINFO's si_pid sets itself to 0 after a few calls of the same function)
I saved the pid to a static variable in the server and the communication suddenly works without usleep. HOWEVER the client still receives signals with _info->si_pid == 0. And even more interresting: the server sends those 100%. They are ack's the server sends. if i filter them out the client will hang waiting for an ack. I am also on Mac btw.

Are you required to do this with SIGUSR1/SIGUSR2 (vs. realtime signals)? non-RT signals are not queued and can be delivered in any order. RT signals are queued, will arrive in order. And, can carry a small payload of data when using sigqueue/rt_sigqueueinfo to send the signal (vs. kill)

The [above] payload data shows up in the (second) info arg. The third arg to the signal handler void *context only contains information on the state/context of the signal recipient (e.g. register values at the time of the signal) and not anything that comes from the signal sender. Thus, it contains no "message data" (and can't be used for this purpose).

Further, with the non-RT signals (again, SIGUSR1/SIGUSR2), the sender can only send one signal to the receiver without receiving some sort of acknowledgement that the receiver has received and processed the signal. For example, if the sender sends two signals with the same value rapidly in succession (e.g. SIGUSR1 and then SIGUSR1), the receiver will [probably] only receive one signal. For non-RT signals, the receiver's "signal pending" mask is set. But, it is a single flag and not a count of the pending signals.

If the sender sends, SIGUSR1 and then SIGUSR2, there is no guarantee that the receiver will receive them in the same order. So, you need feedback from receiver to sender. A baseball analogy ... A pitcher can only throw the ball to the catcher if the catcher's glove is up. And, the pitcher must wait until the catcher sends back the ball (the acknowledgement). A catcher can't field two pitches in rapid sucession.

Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71132499/siginfos-si-pid-sets-itself-to-0-after-a-few-calls-of-the-same-function

@CraigEstey Thanks for your comments.

Yes i am required to only use SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 for the communication.
I only use the void *context to set up the static variable in the signal handler.
The code i provided uses that baseball logic. The client will send the first signal with the first bit. The server receives it and writes the bit to its static buffer and then at the end of its signal handler it sends back a "acknowledgment" in form of SIGUSR1 (if the string is not complete) OR SIGUSR2 (if the string is complete). The client answers with the next bit to that acknowledgement


in this test setup the client will wait for the server to acknowledge each received bit via a signal back to the client which will in turn as answer to that signal send the next bit to the server. This way no signal should interrupt while a signal is being handled.  Nested signal handling is not what makes calling non-async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler unsafe.

At the end of the client's sig_handler you first signal the server, then increment v->i. Consider that the first invocation of sig_handler is the call from main where SIGUSR1 is not blocked; the client may be preempted between kill and v->i++, the server may respond with SIGUSR1 before the client resumes, causing its handler to be reentered and the first bit of the message sent once again, corrupting the transfer. To avoid this, increment v->i before the kill calls.

Thanks for your answer. I changed that but it still dosent solve the question on why the mac kernel replaces the senders pid with 0. Anyhow the program is now working when i just save the pid to a static variable and treat signals with pid 0 as my own.
